# How do I create a (reasonably) simple Contact Us form in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, contactus

I need to create a Contact Us page for a Joomla! site which I'm creating for a friend and I'm not having much luck finding a nice way of doing this. It is just a simple form which contains a few input fields (text boxes, checkboxes and comboboxes), and when the user clicks submit it emails an email address (the email address to use needs to be based on one of the combobox selections).

Can anyone point me in the direction of a component (or core Joomla! functionality) that can help me achieve this?

Cheers,

Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way is to use a forms plugin:

- Chronoforms - http://www.chronoengine.com/component/content/article/1-latest/26-what-is-chronoforms.html
- Ma4Joomla Mailforms - http://www.mad4media.de/mad4joomla-mailforms.html
- RSform! - http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-components/rsform.html

Comment: Thank you! I used Chronoforms and it worked nicely (and has nice tutorials to get a basic form up and going).

Comment: @jspcal You seem to have some knowledge of Joomla.  Any chance of you creating a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account and helping out over there?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [php form](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/php-forms.html) generator. All that you will need is to to add generated code to your web page